# Transient data type in php

Tags: php, types

Is there any data type in php that works like `@transient` of JPA(Java)?

Something like:

```
@transient
private $my_var;
```

Comment: Surely there is a *context* for this "annotation" in PHP? That is, don't ask about "@transient", but ask about the *actual task* in an *actual usage environment*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, but you can define your own serialization method and include or exclude whatever you want.

Example from the documentation: http://php.net/serializable

```
<?php
class obj implements Serializable {
    private $data;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->data = "My private data";
    }
    public function serialize() {
        return serialize($this->data);
    }
    public function unserialize($data) {
        $this->data = unserialize($data);
    }
    public function getData() {
        return $this->data;
    }
}

$obj = new obj;
$ser = serialize($obj);

var_dump($ser);

$newobj = unserialize($ser);

var_dump($newobj->getData());
?>
```